# TensorFlow: Efficient way to get the index of the smallest element in a tensor that isn't zero?

Tags: python, tensorflow, boolean, tensor

I use TensorFlow 1.12. I have a one-dimensional tensor `tag_mask_sizes`, which mostly contains zero's but also a few positive integers. How can I efficiently get the index of the smallest element that isn't zero? I tried the following:

```py
tag_mask_sizes_suppressed = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x if tf.not_equal(x, tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.uint8)) else 9999999, tag_mask_sizes)
        smallest_mask_index = tf.argmin(tag_mask_sizes_suppressed)
```

However, `tf.not_equal()` yields a boolean tensor which I cannot efficiently evaluate in the if-else condition inside the lambda. Are there other elegant solutions like this?

While i normally execute eagerly, this problem occurs inside a function that I use in `tf.Dataset.map()`, which isn't executed eagerly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, your code is equivalent to the following code.

```
tag_mask_sizes_suppressed = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tag_mask_sizes, 0),tag_mask_sizes,tag_mask_sizes+9999999)
smallest_mask_index1 = tf.argmin(tag_mask_sizes_suppressed)
```

The vectorization method will be significantly faster than the `tf.map_fn()`. In addition, there are some vectorization method to get the index of the smallest element in one-dimensional tensor that isn't zero. An example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
# tf.enable_eager_execution()

tag_mask_sizes = tf.constant([2,0,1,3,1,32,0,0,0], dtype=tf.int32)

# approach 1, the disadvantage is that the maximum must be specified and only the first minimum can be found.
tag_mask_sizes_suppressed = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tag_mask_sizes, 0),tag_mask_sizes,tag_mask_sizes+9999999)
smallest_mask_index1 = tf.argmin(tag_mask_sizes_suppressed)

# approach 2, only the first minimum can be found.
tag_mask_sizes_nozeroidx = tf.where(tf.not_equal(tag_mask_sizes, 0))
tag_mask_sizes_suppressed = tf.gather_nd(tag_mask_sizes,tag_mask_sizes_nozeroidx)
smallest_mask_index2 = tag_mask_sizes_nozeroidx[tf.argmin(tag_mask_sizes_suppressed)]

# approach 3, find all minimum
tag_mask_sizes_suppressed = tf.boolean_mask(tag_mask_sizes,tf.not_equal(tag_mask_sizes, 0))
smallest_mask_index3 = tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.equal(tag_mask_sizes,tf.reduce_min(tag_mask_sizes_suppressed))))

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(smallest_mask_index1))
    print(sess.run(smallest_mask_index2))
    print(sess.run(smallest_mask_index3))

# print
2
[2]
[2 4]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I now get this error when using ```fill()```: ```File "/home/.../tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2979, in fill
    "Fill", dims=dims, value=value, name=name)
  File "/home/.../tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 528, in _apply_op_helper
    (input_name, err))
ValueError: Tried to convert 'dims' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?,)``` I do not know the length of ```tag_mask_sizes``` beforehand. Do you happen to know a workaround for this? Maybe copy the array and overwrite it?

Comment: Nevermind, I got your second solution to work! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @EmielBoss You can use `tag_mask_sizes+9999999` replace `tf.fill()` to avoid this error.